# Conditions over pandas dataframe to select specific data

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I would like to select some part of my data to plot, and the conditions are equations.
for example:  select_data =  Qtn < Fr**2 and Qtn > 0.1*Fr
The complete code and data are [here](https://github.com/jc-barreto/Some_tests)

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Qtn'] = np.linspace(0.1,10,100)
df['Fr'] = np.linspace(0.1,200,100)
data_select =  df[(df.Qtn < (70/((1+0.06*df.Fr)**17)+11)) & (df.Qtn > ((32*70-1000)/(100-32*df.Fr))) ]
```

but this is not working because is not making element-wise with the df.Fr
this is my data and what I would like to select is the SC area based on the equation of the lines 1 and 2
[image]

But when I run the code what I can select is this:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply add a condition that your x variable (I don't know which one it is) must be less than the intersection point between the two curves?

Comment: Actually, that solved my problem, Thank you! but I still wonder why the other condition didn't work without this 3rd restriction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation`(32*70-1000)/(100-32*Fr)` becomes negative after the asymptote:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

qt2 = (32*70-1000)/(100-32*Fr)
Fr = np.logspace(-3, 3, 100)
plt.semilogx(Fr, qt2)
```

[image: asymptotic behavior]

So after `Fr > 100/32` (where the denominator in your equation hits 0), you will satisfy both conditions again. So adding a condition to restrict `Fr` values would be a more general solution than restricting to less than the intersection of the curves:

```
df[(df.Qtn < (70/((1+0.06*df.Fr)**17)+11)) & (df.Qtn > ((32*70-1000)/(100-32*df.Fr)) & (df.Fr < 100/32) ]
```